# How to make cmake warn and complain when I try to link 32 bit library against 64 bit project?

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I have a project which is dependent on many legacy libraries (from ~2000). At that time, most of libraries are compiled in 32 bit instead of 64 bit (which is mainstream now). It is not very easy to build them, and their source codes are also not quite available.

I use `cmake` to build my project on win10, **link these legacy libraries**. `CMakeLists.txt` is like

```
# collect all libaries
set(legacy_libs legacy1_32bit.lib legacy2_64bit.lib)

# set up targt
add_library(mylib1 lib1.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main ${legacy_libs})
```

`cmake` doesn't compalint anything when I mix 32 bit and 64 bit libraries, but just report `unresolved external symbol`.

And this error message is sometimes confusing for beginners.

How to force `cmake` to check the lib version consistency, and report it to the user? If so, the debug processdure can be more efficient.

Comment: Cmake is a build manager, not a linker. The linker has to inspect the contents of libraries and determine their suitability to link. Cmake (or any make system) can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. Is there any best practice, which can explicit check the lib version consistency? Though I can handle them because I fully know its mechnism,